# need to install packages on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, package-management

There are libraries and packages for Ubuntu which have this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev libtesseract-dev git cmake build-essential libleptonica-dev

sudo apt-get install liblog4cplus-dev libcurl3-dev
sudo apt-get install beanstalkd
git clone https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr.git
cd openalpr/src
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr -DCMAKE_INSTALL_SYSCONFDIR:PATH=/etc ..
make
wget http://plates.openalpr.com/h786poj.jpg -O lp.jpg alpr lp.jpg
```

I tried to replace `apt-get` by `yum` but this message appears: `No package available`.

Comment: what is in your `/etc/apt/sources.list ` ?

Answer (score 2):

Different distribution do not have the same package names.
Fortunately, most package managers have a "search" function to help
you find packages even if you don't know the exact name.  For Ubuntu,
this is `apt-cache search`.  For CentOS 7, this is `yum search`.  For
example:

```
$ yum search log4c
============================== N/S matched: log4c ==============================
log4c-devel.x86_64 : Header files, libraries and development documentation for
                   : log4c
log4cplus-devel.x86_64 : Development files for log4cplus C++ logging framework
log4cpp-devel.x86_64 : Header files, libraries and development man pages
                     : log4cpp
log4cpp-doc.x86_64 : Development documentation for log4cpp
mingw32-log4c.noarch : MinGW compiled log4c library for the Win32 target
mingw64-log4c.noarch : MinGW compiled log4c library for the Win64 target
log4c.x86_64 : Library for logging application messages
log4cplus.x86_64 : Logging Framework for C++
log4cpp.x86_64 : C++ logging library
log4cxx.i686 : A port to C++ of the Log4j project
log4cxx.x86_64 : A port to C++ of the Log4j project
log4cxx-devel.i686 : Header files for Log4xcc - a port to C++ of the Log4j
                   : project
log4cxx-devel.x86_64 : Header files for Log4xcc - a port to C++ of the Log4j
                     : project
```

The `log4c-devel` package is probably what you want.  Similarly, `yum
search tesseract` shows me a `tesseract-devel` package.